# Calc Style is Missing from TexLive

Tags: texlive, windows, calc, texlive-2020

I am quite new to the tex space. I recently installed Latex in conjunction to texlive (easy editor). I need to write a paper in astronomy and astrophysics but when I use the required template it says calc.sty is missing.

I am running this on Windows 10 and have been searching the internet for hours but can't find a simple way to have this style installed on texlive.

Comment: @noone tlmgr.pl: unknown action: latex-tools;

Comment: `tmlgr install latex-tools`

Comment: @JosephWright tlmgr.pl: package repository https://mirrors.nxthost.com/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl install: package latex-tools not present in repository.
tlmgr.pl: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.